# Why to use actions in Dialogflow

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

I am new to Dialogflow so my question may be too simple. However, I do not understand what is the purpose of naming `actions` in Dialogflow. I have watched videos on youtube and people in them are using `actions` when they have a webhook. For example they may have an if condition in their source code 
(e.g. in python

```
if action == 'action_name':
...
```

)
which executes something particular in this case.

However the json output which is retrieved by the source code has the following form:

```
{
  "id": "123d9e8e-314f-451b-8b15-5e3b55baa980",
  "timestamp": "2018-03-16T17:03:05.987Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Hello",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "effe6b2b-3372-4f89-882f-ff937b2b2abb",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Welcome"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Hello, how can I help you?",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Hello, how can I help you?"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "491d57cb-0af2-45ac-a658-9e47ec6658ce",
  "alternativeResultsFromKnowledgeService": {}
}
```

Since the json data contains the `IntentName` why to bother naming an unique `action` for this specific `intent` when you can get directly the name of the `intent` in your json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to think of this in two ways, depending on exactly what I'm building. (Or sometimes a combination of these two ways.)

1. The Intent Name is a human-usable name, while the Action is something that is more intended for use by the webhook and more directly maps to a function.
2. Since you can have more than one Intent use the same Action, it can be convenient to map a few different ways the user may say something (and the parameters they may send along with them) to the same method. While you could do that by listing all the different Intent names in your code, it is easier to do that on the Dialogflow side.

In truth - use whatever works best for you. I tend to name my Intents and my Actions very similarly, but do branching based on what makes the most sense for the code (which sometimes also includes other values that may be sent).

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. Since, as you say, you may use more than one Intents for the same action then perhaps there is a reason to retrieve from the json data the value of action. However, because I am still new to Dialogflow, I do not have instantly in my mind a case where you will use more Intents for the same action (but it must certainly be some cases where it is necessary)...